# Add separator to actions of a QTableView?

Tags: qt4, qtableview

In `QMenu` there's a `addSeparator()` function available, what's the equivalent in QTableView?

I only see the function to add an action (which is `addAction()`), how am I supposed to add a separator when I set context menu mode to `ActionContextMenu`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
QAction *separator = new QAction(this);
separator->setSeparator(true);
addAction(separator);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set `ContextMenuPolicy` to `Qt::CustomContextMenu` and then construct your custom menu using `QWidget::actions()` and your separators.

Comment: Looks like to be the only possible way ;-P